# How exactly do I update FlatList's data using Apollo Client's fetchMore method?

Tags: react-native, pagination, apollo-client, react-native-flatlist

My GraphQL backend returns data in the form:

```
{
  data: {
    feed: {
      A: [...],
      B: [...]
    }
  }
}
```

Where my frontend merges `A` and `B` using a sort on some field present within the data, and then uses React Native's `FlatList` to display them as a single array. I'm using Apollo client to query my backend like so:

```
const { fetchMore, loading, data, error } = useQuery(fetchQuery, {variables: fetchArgs});

if (loading) {...}
if (error) {...}

let A = [];
let B = [];
if (data!.feed.A) A = data!.feed.A
if (data!.feed.B) B = data!.feed.B
let feedData = sortedMerge(A,B);

return (
  <FlatList
    data={feedData}
    ...
    onEndReached{
      //update fetchArgs
      fetchMore({
        variables: fetchArgs,
        updateQuery: // Not sure if I need to do anything here?
      }).then(result => {
        // Maybe this is where I update?
      })
    }
)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how or where to get the new data, say `A'` and `B'` merged and concatenated with `feedData` so that my `FlatList` can update as efficiently as possible?

I guess I'm having trouble because I can't just directly update the list and need to do a little bit of preprocessing, but no matter where I update `feedData`, either in the `then` block after `fetchMore` or outside of it, the `FlatList` never seems to update.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your merge logic in a `useMemo`:

```
const { fetchMore, loading, data, error } = useQuery(fetchQuery, {variables: fetchArgs});

const feedData = useMemo(() => {
  if (data) {
    const { A, B } = data.feed;
    return sortedMerge(A,B);
  } else return [];
},[data]);

if (loading) {...}
if (error) {...}

return (
  <FlatList
    data={feedData}
    ...
    onEndReached = {() => fetchMore({ variables: fetchArgs })}
  />
)
```

Executing `fetchMore` *should* cause `data` to be updated which will trigger the `useMemo` and update your `feedData` variable.

However you'll still need to [merge the paginated results](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#merging-paginated-results) into the client-side cache.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about merging paginated results. I'll try your suggestion after making some changes and updating.